# Powershell input a dash "-" in each line of the file at character 79 if a number or letter is present

Tags: powershell

I could really use some help.  I got most of my code to work but I am having issues finding a way to only add a - at every character location of 79 - but only if a number or letter exists.  The code below adds the dash at the correct location but I can't figure out a way to not add a dash if the character at location 79 is a space.

(gc C:\test\tst1.txt) -replace ".{79}" , "$&-" |  sc C:\test\out.txt

Comment: You want to replace character 79 if it’s not a space?

Comment: correct.  I want to replace character 79 with a dash if a value is there.  if there is a space, I dont want to add the dash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to insert `-` at character 79 that meets the required conditions:

```
(Get-Content C:\test\tst1.txt) -replace '^.{79}(?<=[a-z0-9])','$&-' |
   Set-Content C:\test\out.txt
```

`(?<=)` is a positive lookbehind for a character from the character set `a-z` (case-insensitive) or `0-9`

---

If you want to insert `-` after every 79 characters that meet the conditions, you can do the following:

```
$regex = '(.{78}[^a-z0-9])|(.{78}[a-z0-9])'
$sb = { param($m)
        if ($m.Groups[2].Success) {
            "{0}-" -f $m.Groups[2]
        } else {
            $m.Groups[1]
        }
}
Get-Content c:\test\tst1.txt | Foreach-Object {
    [regex]::Replace($_,$regex,$sb)
} | Set-Content C:\test\out.txt
```

This scenario will likely have a more verbose solution since PowerShell regex does not support match resets.

---

Note that your comments and your post description do not have the same requirements. The code above adds a `-` at character position 79 and shifts previous positions 79-EndOfString to the right. It does not replace. Performing an actual replace, would look like the following:

```
(Get-Content C:\test\tst1.txt) -replace '(^.{79})(?<=[a-z0-9]).','$1-' |
   Set-Content C:\test\out.txt
```

Comment: In my testing it replaced spaces as well.

Comment: @DougMaurer Test `'1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111119222222' -replace '^.{79}(?<=[a-z0-9])','$&-'` vs. `'111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 222222' -replace '^.{79}(?<=[a-z0-9])','$&-'`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  New to coding and having fun but have a lot to learn! Another item I didn't elaborate on is its just the 79th character.  Its every 79th character in line in a text file.  I removed the ^ from the .{79} section of the code which seemed to work but ever so often, in my text file, a dash is added at character 162.  This may be due to the script replacing the character with a dash instead of inserting a - and preserving the character where the dash is being added.  Apologies for not explaining things well on my end =\.  I will continue to play around with the code.

Comment: Found part of the issue.  I replaced the ,'$1-' with ,'$&-' but ever so often I am still getting dashes in character 162. Hmm looking more into it

Comment: @oomotofxoo I added a section that will replace every 79th character that meets the conditions.